# How do you add multiple countif statements in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

My current formula will just count any dup as "2X" but if it has 3 dups I would like to see "3X" and
"4X" for 4 dups and so on. How can I add on to my formula?

=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$14736, $A2)>1, "2X", "")

Comment: don't use countif with if. just use countif, and then add "X" at the end. try `=countif($A$2:$A$14736, $A2)&"X"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$14736, $A2)<2,"",COUNTIF($A$2:$A$14736, $A2)-1 & "X")
```

[image]

In the above example we have an original value and two duplicates.
If there are no duplicates *(only the original)*, then the formula leaves the cell blank.
*(if you want to count the total number of items (original + duplicates), then just drop the **-1** in the formula)*

Comment: he doesn't need `-1` I think.

Answer (score 2):

So you are doing this:

```
Count the number of occurences
If the count is larger than 1, print "2X"
```

Why don't you do this:

```
Count the number of occurences
Concatenate that number with "X"
```

Comment: Poster's original formula gave a Null if there were no duplicates.